# How to remove the array which is displayed with all the records in rails show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a show page as follows:

ins/_show.html.haml:

```
  = @employee.ins.each do |emp|
    %p
      %strong Name:
      = emp.name
    %p
      %strong Relationship:
      = emp.relationship
```

and the piece code where i am calling the above show is:

```
  = render :partial => 'insurances/show', locals: { employee: @employee }
```

When i'm calling render 'show', i am getting values along with array of fields like:

```
Name: abc

Relationship: def

[#<Insurance id: 4, name: "abc", relationship: "def", employee_id: 4>]
```

How to remove the last the last array fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= @employee.ins.each do |emp|
```

in this line `=` is printing the values, 
use

```
- @employee.ins.each do |emp|
```

Comment: @sachin As you are still in learning phase I would like to give you a quick tip. Instead of writing `emp.name` use `emp.try(:name)`, this will prevent nilClass error if in any case @employee's ins is nil